# What statups are expecting while asking to solve a programming challenge before hand?

Tags: algorithm, oop, coding-style, startup

I have applied to couple of startups and most of them are asking to solve programming challenge before they start on the interviewing candidate.
I have submitted couple of the solution and all the time getting rejected in the initial screening.
Now what i think is, they will see my coding style, algorithm and OOD concepts that i have used to solve the problem. Can you guys input more on it as what other details are taken into consideration and how can i improve my coding for getting selected.
By the way, i did all my coding in either Java/Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, I am a new grad too... One thing I notice: When you do the exercise home, they expect you to use the best algorithm out there. In my opinion code modularity, even on a small function is key. Put lot effort into the code because they are not just judging you, but comparing you against other candidate. The one which seems to have put the more effort wins.

ps: Ask this question on programmers.stackexchange, you will obtain some good inputs there.